# I can't save things in terminal

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-mate

I have just installed Ubuntu mate 32 bit and can't seem to save things when I put them into terminal. I hit "contr x" then "y" but it doesn't seem to save them?

Comment: Do you mean, save something you wrote into an editor, like vim or emacs? or do you just want to copy/paste commands?

Comment: Those keystrokes correspond to nano.  Please post what error messages you get, and make sure that you're saving something in a directory you can write to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `nano`, you can save with Contr + o and Enter. And exit with Contro + x and Enter. Make sure, that you have rights to edit this file